# No padding-effect in custom ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview, padding, android-custom-view

I've got an issue assigning *padding-values* to my custom ImageView. Please note, that I'm not extending `ImageView` but `View`:

```
public class CustomImageView extends View
```

The image is loaded from the assets folder via path. Source- and Target-`Rect` are calculated in `onLayout(...)` and the bitmap is assigned in `onDraw(...)`.

Good news: The Image is displayed ;-)

Bad News: Assigning *padding-values* by `setPadding(...)` has no effect on the image (problem to solve!). I tested this with a "normal" `ImageView`-Object and it worked like desired. But unfortunately the task is to extend my custom class from `View`, not `ImageView`. So if anybody knows how to solve this - and I'm definitely not the first one with this problem ;-) - let me know!

Here's the `onDraw`-Method, no magic:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (bitmap != null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, targetRect, paint);
}
```

Comment: can you post your `onDraw` method?

Comment: read View javadocs, section "Size, padding and margins"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting paddings to view, they should be considered during the drawing. You can achieve this, by creating a `BitmapDrawable` variable in your custom view, and then initialize it and draw according to padding, for example.

```
private BitmapDrawable mDrawable;

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mDrawable != null) {
        int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
        int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
        int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

        int contentWidth = getWidth() - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
        int contentHeight = getHeight() - paddingTop - paddingBottom;

        mDrawable.setBounds(paddingLeft, paddingTop,
                paddingLeft + contentWidth, paddingTop + contentHeight);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```